# Loop through Kendo Gantt Rows

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a Kendo Gantt.
On "onDataBound" event I need to loop through each row of the grid part and get the columns value.
How can I do that?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the kendo example and modifying it slightly here is a dojo: [OnDataBound Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/IvUFe)

All I have done on the onDataBound Event is this:

```
function onDataBound(e){
            kendoConsole.log("DataBound fired::" + e);
            console.log(e);

            var datasource = $("#gantt").data('kendoGantt').dataSource.data();


            if(datasource !== null)
            {
                datasource.forEach(function(item){
                  kendoConsole.log("Item Found:: " + item.id + ' ' +  item.title); 
                  console.log(item); 
                });
            }


          }
```

I check for the datasource we have bound and then just iterate through it with a `forEach` loop to display the id and the title of the task item. You can obviously modify the function to do what you want. If you check the console you will see the underlying items and all their properties.

Hopefully this helps you. If you need any more info let me know and I will update the answer.